# What does 'have a whiff of sg ABOUT IT' mean?

Tags: idioms

I could google what the first part means yet I can't see what "about it" adds to it. Does the expression mean the same without the last part?

Comment: It's not idiomatic without that part. You don't just have an air. You have that air about you. Same for whiff.

Answer (score 1):

**whiff of something (sg)** [TDF](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/whiff) an idiom

1. . Lit. the smell or odor of something. (*Typically: get ~; catch ~; have ~; take ~; give someone ~.)

> Did you get a whiff of the turkey roasting? Yummy. I caught a whiff of
>   something rather unpleasant in the attic. I think there is a dead
>   mouse up there.

2. . Fig. a bit of knowledge of something. (*Typically: get ~; catch ~; give someone ~.)

> The boss got a whiff of problems in the accounting department. No
>   one will get a whiff of your crime with the police. I'll see to
>   that.

'About it' is not necessarily ... necessary.  It depends on the context and grammatical construction you choose. The necessary is 'sg'.

Answer (score -1):

"about" means "in the area of", "nearby", as per the [second definition of this entry.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/about)

"whiff" is smell or odor, so to say something "has a whiff about it" means there is a smell in the nearby area. It's slightly less definite than to say 'something has a whiff", which means that the whiff is definitely a property of the object, but means that the whiff is nearby and is probably associated with the object.

Comment: Now that makes sense

Comment: Would the downvoter care to comment?